# SchemaCrawler not able to find MSSQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, schema, schemacrawler

I'm trying to export a schema from MSSQL database using SchemaCrawler & jTDS driver (version 1.3.1).

The command is:

```
./schemacrawler.sh \
  -server=sqlserver \
  -password= \
  -command=schema \
  -outputformat=png \
  -outputfile=./output/result.png \
  -infolevel=standard \
  -schemas=.*XYZ.*DOMAIN.user.* \
  -tabletypes=TABLE \
  -tables=.* \
  -routinetypes= \
  -loglevel=ALL \
  -url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server.com:1433/XYZ\;instance=dbinstance\;useNTLMv2=TRUE\;domain=DOMAIN\;user=user\;password=pwd
```

The DB tables were created under the user's schema, e.g.: DOMAIN\user.Table1

The connection URL and regex to match the schema work fine - when I launch the Database Manager with the same connection string, I can see all the tables listed as DOMAIN\user.table.

However, when I run the script from a Docker container, I'm getting:

```
Mar 14, 2017 8:53:18 PM schemacrawler.crawl.SchemaCrawler crawlTables
INFO: Crawling tables
Mar 14, 2017 8:53:18 PM schemacrawler.crawl.TableRetriever retrieveTables
INFO: Retrieving tables for schema: "XYZ"."DOMAIN\user"
Mar 14, 2017 8:53:18 PM schemacrawler.crawl.TableRetriever retrieveTables
FINER: Retrieving table types: [TABLE]
Mar 14, 2017 8:53:18 PM schemacrawler.crawl.MetadataResultSet close
INFO: Processed 0 rows for <retrieveTables>
Mar 14, 2017 8:53:18 PM schemacrawler.crawl.SchemaCrawler crawlTables
INFO: Retrieved 0 tables
```

Any ideas why it can't see the tables?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Making Connections to a Database](http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/database-support.html), on the SchemaCrawler website, and see if that helps. Please try `-schemas=.*user\.dbo.*` and see if that works for you.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://www.SchemaCrawler.com)

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Unfortunately it didn't help :( When I check the log, it correctly parses the schemas and finds the right one. But for some reason it doesn't see any tables in it. Can I somehow get the exact query it uses to fetch the tables?

Comment: @Stano Please open a GitHub issue - https://github.com/sualeh/SchemaCrawler/issues